# undefined method `tempfile' for "\x89PNG\r\n":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have following in my controller spec for uploading file:

```
post :file_upload,
   user_id: @project.user.username,
   id: @project.name,
   branch_name: 'master',
   commit: 'first commit',
   file: fixture_file_upload("files/happypanda.png", "image/png")
```

I think this is the right way to upload files but it keeps giving me:

> NoMethodError:    undefined method `tempfile' for "\x89PNG\r\n":String

Let me what other relevant information should I post.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into trouble with `fixture_file_upload` recently too, but the good news is that that method is just a shortcut for roughly the following code:

```
Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new("#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/#{file_path}", mime_type)
```

So try using this lower-level call, and if that works better for you, you can even wrap it up in a helper method:

```
def file_upload(name)
  Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new("#{Rails.root}/spec/_files/#{name}")
end
```

(Note that there's nothing special about the path `/spec/fixtures`, that's just the assumed default.)

Comment: Sorry @Topher I had already tried `Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(File.expand_path("spec/factories/files/happypanda.png"), "image/png")` It gave me the same error.